# Save JPEG image in documents directory - iOS

Tags: ios, image, encoding, save

I have a yuv image, which I convert to jpeg using some function. After that, if I try to save the image in the camera roll, I am able to do so. But when I try to write it to documents directory, using the `writeToFile:` method of `NSData`, it fails. some error 512, bad address.

If I use the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` method, and pass to it the jpeg image that I created, then it gets saved properly in documents directory.

What if I want to save the jpeg that i created, directly, without encoding it again using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`?

Comment: Please post your code if possible.

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps also log the path you're trying use with `writeToFile`, because when I have problems, it always something simple in my file name.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this very similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547894/the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-cocoa-error-512

Comment: I take a file name abc. I try to save a yuv image, it gets saved. Keeping everything same, I just change the data to be saved to jpeg data, then it doesn't get saved.   I keep the path same as I kept for yuv image, including the name of the file. This should not be the problem of file name or some other setting I think.   
  
@Paul  
I did come across various such links (including yours) but they didn't help. I did a lot of searching before posting the query. Maybe there is some particular requirement for the jpeg encoding.